# Repartition a non LVM system with LVM

Tags: partition, lvm, disk

I have installed my system without LVM but I need it now.

How can I repartition my disk with LVM and keep all my system files?

I know this would need backup, but I have never used it yet and don't know wich tool would best suit that situation.

Comment: There is a tool to convert to LVM ( https://github.com/g2p/blocks#readme ). I wrote a howto do it manually but it's in German https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/Howto/LVM_nachträglich_einrichten/ - conversion aside you also have to make the system bootable for root-on-lvm. Backing up all files and reinstalling with LVM is not the worst option here. You should have a backup in any case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some free disk space you can do this. But this can be long and not so sample process. The best you can do is to copy your personal files to external disk or cloud storage. The commands with can help you to pack the files in bundles (if you have a lot of small files) are `tar`, `zip`.

The process of replacing current disks with LVM is in few words:

- create PV from free space
- create VG from from PV
- create LV in VG
- create filesystem on LV
- mount filesystem
- copy files to release some filesystem
- unmount this filesystem
- remount LV filesystem  on the place of above filesystem
- create PV from unmounted filesystem
- add this PV to VG
- repeat with next filesystem

After you finish with root partition you will need to edit `/etc/fstab` and update grub